# QWidget clips painting on mouseMoveEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm creating a marquee selection type tool in a QWidget and it all works fine, except for a rendering bug when dragging the marquee. If I call update without any arguments everything works beautifully, but if I call update to only include the region of the marquee as the user is dragging, then two of the edges get cutoff if the mouse is moving at a moderate speed.

Here's an image of what it looks like while dragging towards the lower right corner:

Screenshot while clicking and dragging in the widget

[image]

I thought replacing update() with repaint() might fix it but that didn't work either.

What is the correct way that I should be doing this? I've included some very basic code that demonstrates the problem.

```
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{

public:

Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) override
{
    startPt = e->pos();
    rect = QRect();
    update(); // clear the entire widget
}

void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e) override
{
    rect = QRect(startPt, e->pos()).normalized();
    update(rect.adjusted(-2,-2,2,2)); // adjusted to include stroke
}

void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override
{
    QPainter p(this);

    p.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 2));
    p.drawRect(rect);
}

private:
    QRect rect;
    QPoint startPt;
};
```

Comment: You could show an image of your problem to understand you better.

Comment: What if you call `update(rect.adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));` instead? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Increasing the size of the QRect that is passed to the update function helps but it still messes up if the mouse is moving fast enough.

Comment: May be, this could work better: Always request update() of complete widget. In `mousePressEvent()`, you store mouse pos. for start. In `paintEvent()`, you get current mouse position for end (with `mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos())`). I used this to prevent that the rubber band lags behind mouse cursor (as there might be a recognizable delay between processing of mouse event and re-paint). I cannot remember where I got this technique from but I found the resp. code in a custom widget I've done some months ago.

Comment: I guess it's because of the real rendering process is different with paint process. If render each into files the problem will not occur. https://github.com/arkceajin/QtDemos/blob/master/paintEvent/paintEvent.h

Comment: Yeah, my conclusion is it has something to do with being different processes. It's not a showstopper, I can just update the entire widget, or pad the bounds a reasonable amount. I was just hoping there was some quick fix that I had missed.